# Points disappear in final frame of gganimate chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am developing a `gganimate` animation that shows the data points over time between two metrics, x and y, with a line chart trailing behind them showing 'where you've been'.  Something along the lines of this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(dplyr)
library(gapminder)

gm <- gapminder %>%
  filter(continent == 'Oceania') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp, group = country, col = country)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(size = pop), show.legend = FALSE, alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_size(range = c(2, 12)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  theme_bw() +
  transition_reveal(year) +
  #labs(title = "Year: {frame_time}") +
  NULL

animate(gm, end_pause = 10)
```

Which creates this animation:
[image]

There's something weird about the `end_pause` frame, though.  For some reason, all of the visible dots except one disappear, leaving only the trails:

[image]

How do I get *all* of them to stay, not just the one?

Comment: This is caused by a change in the code for `transition_reveal` in 1.0.8, that aimed to fix a [different issue](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/409) but inadvertently caused this one. My [original workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64135523/8449629) should still work for your case. I'll report this on GitHub.

Comment: [Reported](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/480) on GH with another workaround. Both seems to work for your example above.